# The thing that we use to remotely open the door in English

Tags: single-word-requests

What is "the thing that, in its simplest form, has a receiver and a button, and we use to open the door when somebody rings the door bell" called in English?

When I'm speaking English I almost always ask somebody to answer the door or I answer the door myself but today I was thinking, what is that "thing" exactly called, is it a "Door Answerer" or an Intercom?

In my native language, it is called '*AiPhone*' or '*EF-EF*'.

Comment: It depends exactly what you're talking about, but the term that comes to my mind is "door buzzer".

Comment: @KevinWorkman: That's such a nice word, why didn't that come to my mind :)

Comment: The intercom is the box you talk into and what you listen to. You *buzz* someone in.

Comment: [Aiphone](http://www.aiphone.com/) seems to be an international manufacturer of intercoms and security systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly, these devices are called *[Intercom](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/intercom)s*.

More specifically, the one used to answer the door is called the *door-phone.* There are differences in terminology used in various countries for the same product.

[AiPhone](http://www.aiphone.net.au/) (Australia) calls it the 'Intercom'.

Samsung markets similar systems in the US as '[Door Phones](http://us.aving.net/news/view.php?articleId=193227&mn_name=).'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the entire unit is called the Intercom, while the buzzer button to buzz someone in is just a part of it.